# Quicksort: Why wrong output

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I want to sort the given array using quicksort.
So I wrote this code in c for quicksort algorithm but its not giving me correct answer.Its giving me the same output as the input.
 eg: If i give input as
 3
 2
 1
then it is giving
Output:
3
2
1
Please help and tell me where is the mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void quicksort(int a[],int p,int r);
int partition(int a[],int p,int r);
void swap(int a,int b);
int main()
{
    int n,i,p,r;
    printf("ENter no of elements");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    printf("ENter the elements");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    p=1;
    r=n;
    quicksort(a,1,n);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
void quicksort(int a[],int p,int r)
{
    int q;
    if(p<r)
    {
    q = partition(a,p,r);
    quicksort(a,p,q-1);
    quicksort(a,q+1,r); 
    }

}
int partition(int a[],int p,int r)
{
    int x,i,j;
    x=a[r];
    i=p-1;
    for(j=p;j<=r-1;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]<=x)
        {
            i=i+1;
            swap(a[i],a[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(a[i+1],a[r]);

    return (i+1);
}
    void swap(int a,int b)
{
    int t;
    t=a;
    a=b;
    b=t;
}
```

Comment: Hello, remember that StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. It might be worth having a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which has some tips on how to ask a great question that'll get you the answer you're looking for. Maybe can elaborate on what you've already tried and what you've found so far.

Comment: As an aside, you are aware that `#include <stdlib.h>` gives you access to the [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function? If you have the choice, *don't* try to reimplement what's already there.

Comment: Generic debugging hint: Check your assumptions. Check intermediary results. It should have been rather easy to find out that no swapping is being done by `swap()`, reducing the scope of your problem considerably...

Answer (score 0):

```
void swap(int a,int b)
```

This line is taking the two parameters as copies of the values. The swapping is done on he copies.

```
void swap(int* a, int* b)
```

This is the C-style of passing parameters by reference. You need to pass the references then:

```
swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
```